# Linux network namespace: process remains after killing container

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, linux-namespaces

I create network namespace as `ip netns add myns`, and then start a process inside the container as daemon `ip netns exec myns process -D`. However after I delete the namespace with `ip netns del myns`, the process still remains on the host.

Is it expected? What is the right way to clean up the process while deleting Linux containers?

Thanks.

Comment: The man page suggests running `ip netns pids myns | xargs kill` before deleting the namespace.

Comment: @IanAbbott, thanks, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The namespace will only get deleted once the last reference to the namespace is removed.

Answer (score 1):

From: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html

> To prevent this the processes running in `net0` should be killed before
> deleting the netns:
>
> ```
> $ ip netns pids net0 | xargs kill
> $ ip netns del net0
> ```